# LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle Decoding token in controller

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to find it in documentation if there is a way to decode token into user id. Does this bundle provide such option/service? 
Thanks

Comment: I got this so far, but not sure how to convert actual token. Implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface
`$jwtManager = $this->container->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager');
            $x = $jwtManager->decode($token);`

Answer (score 0):

So the solution that worked was to create new firewall rule

```
    auto_login:
        pattern: ^/auto_login
        anonymous: true
        stateless: true
        lexik_jwt:
            query_parameter:
                enabled: true
                name:    bearer
```

Now I can pass token as a get query

```
/auto_login/redirect_to_some_url?bearer=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1...
```

and in the controller for the route "/auto_login" I create the session for the user if token is good, and I'm auto login, looks and works good.

```
/**
 * @Route("/auto_login", name="auto_login")
 * @Route("/auto_login/{redirect}")
 */
public function autoLoginAction(Request $request, $redirect = null)
{
    $current_user_id = $this->getUser()->getId();
    if ($redirect && $current_user_id) {

        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->find($current_user_id);

        $sf_token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
        $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($sf_token);
        $this->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($sf_token));

        $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $sf_token);
        $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch('security.interactive_login', $event);

        return $this->redirectToRoute($redirect);
    } else {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('login');
    }
}
```